# Remove/replace Chatter feed fields

Tags: configuration

Does anyone know how to remove the fields on the Chatter feed layout?
Specifically Other and Hassan Rehan are Subject and Owner fields respectively.
I want to use different fields, or remove them entirely.

Cannot figure out where the configuration for this is.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can remove/customize (https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVruUAF/chatter-filter-my-own-personal-actions-and-remove-them-from-my-feed)